# Selecting an value from a table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to make an "entity" selector when the user run a function. For example look the code

```
foo = {
    {['selected'] = 1},
    {['selected'] = 0}
}

local arrow = true

if arrow then
    for k, v in pairs(foo) do
        if v.selected == 1 then
            v.selected = 0
        end
        if v.selected == 0 then
            v.selected = 1
        end
    end
end

for k,v in pairs(foo) do
    for ks,vs in pairs(v) do
        print(vs)
    end
end
```

So as yours can see, i has a table foo, when the user press the arrow it will change the ['selected'] value betwen 1 and 0. But when i run it change all both values to 1, and i only want one to be set to 1 and the others to 0. I'm using Lua, and it need to be in lua, if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

```lua
        if v.selected == 1 then
            v.selected = 0
        end
        if v.selected == 0 then
            v.selected = 1
        end
```

Read it out aloud:
If selected is 1, set it to 0.
Then, if it is 0, set it to 1.

Does this make sense?

Instead you would like the second condition to only trigger, if the first one did not. Alias, `elseif`

```lua
        if v.selected == 1 then
            v.selected = 0
        elseif v.selected == 0 then
            v.selected = 1
        end
```

Now it won't execute both. Still quite chunky code, let's use a ternary operator here:

```lua
v.selected = v.selected == 1 and 0 or 1
```

And if you had booleans, you can even do:

```lua
v.selected = not v.selected
```